# Расчитать направление rb.AddForce относительно наклона другого обьекта

Tags: unity3d

Есть объект(1). К нему прикреплен еще один(2). 1-ый вращается, а вместе с ним вращается 2-ой. Для второго объекта вращение всегда(0,0,0), в то время когда 1-ый постоянно вращается вокруг своей оси.[image: 1]

3-ий объект(допустим пуля) должен вылетать из 2 и лететь вперед по оси вращения(т.е rb.Addforce должен рассчитываться опираясь на угол вращения 1 объекта)[image: 2]

Но только один раз.[image: 3]

Comment: Зачем эти загадки? Объект 1, объект 2. Напиши ты что тебе конкретно нужно рассчитать. У трансформа есть свойство rotation тебе оно что ли нужно?

Comment: Смотри, есть вот эта серая штучка(2 ой объект) он должен создать 3(пулю), она должна лететь по направлению поворота(т.е если угол 90 он должен лететь вправо, если угол 45 вверх и вправо и т д.) реализуется это через Addforce.

Comment: ‍♂️ Ты сейчас то же самое написал, но другими словами. Я же тебе ответил. У компонента Transform есть свойство rotation, оно тебе даст вращение объекта. Либо используй transform.forward/right/up и т.д оно вернет тебе ось этого трансформа. Вместо того, чтобы писать "у меня есть эта штучка, нужно, чтобы другая штучка делала то то", ты мог конкретно написать, что у тебя есть персонаж, есть оружие и нужно, чтобы пуля летела туда, куда персонаж смотрит. Или тебе нужно, чтобы кто-то код написал?

Comment: Открою тайну, у объектов есть не только локальный поворот `localRotation`/`localEulerAngles`, тот что 0 но и глобальный `rotation`/`eulerAngles`. К дулу ствола крепят пустой GameObject, который есть точка спавна пуль и указатель поворота/направления. Задача решена и никто ничего в ручную не высчитывает.